# Redshift: Cross join make data disappear

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, cross-join

I have a weird issue in Redshift with a crossjoin. 
I am generating days and want to join them with some ids.
The sample query is this:

```
with ids as (
Select number as id
from models.number_10000 
limit 10
),
day as (
SELECT
TO_CHAR(DATEADD(day,num.number,CAST(DATEADD(day,-463,GETDATE()) AS DATE)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_string
FROM 
(Select * from models.number_10000 limit 463)
as num
)
SELECT 
    id,date_string
from ids,day
```

Everything is working fine so far.
However, if I group by then I have no results.

```
with ids as (
Select number as id
from models.number_10000 
limit 10
),
day as (
SELECT
TO_CHAR(DATEADD(day,num.number,CAST(DATEADD(day,-463,GETDATE()) AS DATE)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_string
FROM 
(Select * from models.number_10000 limit 463)
as num
)
SELECT 
    id,date_String
from ids,day
group by 1,2
```

How is this happening? I have never faced something similar. I guess it's something with the cross join and the group by but it seems very strange.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the following:

1. State your `JOIN` explicitly (ANSI92 Style).
2. State the names of items you want to be grouped explicitly.
3. Moreover - remove your `GROUP BY` statement (as you do not have any aggregate functions) and have a `DISTINCT` clause in your select statement.

Comment: It's still the same, I tried: with ids as (
Select number as id
from models.number_10000 
limit 10
),
day as (
SELECT
TO_CHAR(DATEADD(day,num.number,CAST(DATEADD(day,-463,GETDATE()) AS DATE)),'YYYY-MM-DD') as date_string
FROM 
(Select * from models.number_10000 limit 463)
as num
)
SELECT 
distinct 
id,date_String
from ids CROSS JOIN day